# Modifying windows registry when running automated test scripts using robot framework

Tags: registry, robotframework

I've been working on automation and robot framework for a couple of months now and have been able to find most of the answers that I need by searching on the internet. But currently I'm stuck with how to modify windows registry during running test cases.

When I searched online, I found this python package - WinRegistry 0.8.3 for modifying the registry. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winregistry/0.8.3

Python was able to download and install this package when I ran "pip install winregistry".

I added "Library winregistry" to my script's settings and I am able to navigate to the keywords (read value, write value) when I press Ctrl+B on the keyword in my script.
But at run-time, robot framework is not able to find the keyword. It errors out saying "No keyword with name 'read value' found."

Do I need to any other step to get this to work ? If anybody knows, please help me out.

Thanks, in advance !

Comment: I got around this issue by writing a batch file which uses the reg.exe to change the registry setting.

But it'll be nice to have keywords available so that I can directly update it from the scripts. Preferably the keywords should be part of the Selenium Library

Answer (score 2):

`winregistry` uses `winreg` which is only available for Python 3. For Python 2.7 it should use `_winreg`.

I replace all `winreg` with `_winreg` in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\winregistry\winregistry.py` and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on the PyPI page you linked, you should import the module as `winregistry.robot` and not just `winregistry`

```
*** Settings ***
Library    winregistry.robot
```

This is likely because this module isn't strictly meant for Robot Framework usage, and the module's author separated the keywords into a subclass of his module.

Comment: I did that too. I apologize for not having added that in when I posted the question.